# Limited Data Set and Risk of Overfitting

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, overfitting

I'm performing some predictive modelling on a set of stocks in an index.

My universe is about 800 stocks with data ranging from 2000 through 2017.

I'm able to successfully train and test a model using the available data using the classic split of data into a training set and test set.

After training the model I need to back test a strategy on the index.  In effect, I end up using the same historical data on these securities and apply my predictive model derived on the same data as described above.

Won't this lead to overfitted results as I'll be asking the model to predict results on some of the data it was trained on?  How do I get around this without having to find completely new securities?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us more details about your procedure?

Comment: You're right that you may have an overfitting problem. Two approaches are to test your trading strategy in other time periods or perhaps other markets than what you used to develop your trading strategy. A problem with testing on other markets is that markets are cross-sectionally correlated, hence you're not really using independent test data. A problem with testing over different time periods is that markets may have structurally changed and the old data isn't relevant.